# google drive notifications in tray

Tags: notifications, google-drive-api, dropbox

There is a quite good feature in Dropbox - changed files tray notifications. When you working in collaboration it is VERY useful. Do you know how to achieve the same in Google Drive? I found Google Drive API, but I need notifications in tray (message balloons). Thanks.

Comment: not about programming or the api

Comment: You need chrome/firefox extension or app. It can detect any updates and pop a balloon/notifications. Share your requirements.